# How to save a HTML table in MySQL database - efficient way to do this?

Tags: php, html, mysql, sql

I have a php website with a html table. The user is able to modify each of the contained cells (much like in Excel), e.g. change it's content or font-size. My current approach is to save these cells in a one-to-many relationship: One mysql table for the different tables and one mysql table with the cells. To each "table-object" there are several "cell-objects" assigned. The problem I have at the moment is, that this generates really a lot of db querys (about 2200 when saving or opening one table, one for each cell). I think that this really is too much, isn't it (or at least not good way of practice)?

Can anyone give me a hint, what other way I could achieve this? Or is it ok like this anyway?

Thanks in advance,

katze_sonne

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could probably collect all the cell data into a multidimensional array of cells split into rows:

```
$table = array(
    array(0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5),
    array(0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5),
    array(0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5)
);
```

Then serialize the whole array using PHP `serialize()` and save it in a single MySQL `TEXT` field.

When you read from the database, you can just `unserialize()` the field and it's back to being a normal PHP array which you can loop through and print out the table.

Comment: Ok, thanks a lot! That is what I was looking for! :D I think I will use `MEDIUMTEXT` instead of `TEXT` to be sure that the size won't exceed the maximum length of the datatype, though.

Answer (score 0):

You can consider serializing your data to one of the following formats before sending it to the database to store

1. Yaml
2. JSon
3. XML

All these are machine readable, plain text formats. So you can convert them back to objects in your code after retriving